# Issue while passing extra parameters with jquery trigger function

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I have a problem while passing extraparameters with jquery trigger function. The extra parameters are not passing. Code :

```
//click event binding with button goes here
$("#b").bind({ click: 
   function (e, x, y) { 
   alert(x + " " + y);   //here`s the problem, showing undefined (expecting top & left  
}                        //offset() of dropped button 
});

//here making the button draggable for drag drop functionality (applying jquery-ui)
$("#b").draggable({ helper : "clone" });

//here creating a droppable area ( here i am dropping a draggable button)
$(".droppable").live({ mouseenter: function () {
    $(this).droppable({
        accept: "#b",              // accepting only button whose id = b
        drop: function (ev, ui) {
            alert("dropped");      //alert is showing means droppable works fine  
            var y = ui.offset.top;
            var x = ui.offset.left;
            ui.draggable.trigger("click", [x , y]); // here i am triggering the click event
        }                                           // for button and passing x and y as an     
    });                                             // extra parameter 
}
});
```

Comment: For your information, those comments' syntax is amazingly wrong. And by the way, the code should be working (after dropping the comments)

Comment: have you tried `$(this).click();` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I plotted the situation and it works fine for me (With the same code).

What are the elements that are draggable and droppable ?
Mine are :

```
    <div id="b" style="width:200px;height:200px;background-color:red"></div>

    <div class="droppable" style="width:400px;height:200px;background-color:green"></div>
```

My suggesstions :

Add `console.log(x, y)` after you get the offset values - there's a chance that the draggable element does not have them (and the values are undefined)

Alter your click handler the following way, so you can handle both user clicks and trigger clicks:

```
function (e, x, y) { 
                if(typeof x !== "undefined" && typeof y !== undefined) {
                    // do trigger logic
                    return;
                }
                // do click logic
            }
```

Comment: Nice addition to use `console.log()` to check parameter is going through before doing anything else.